# Is there a way to run a custom script immediately after mount a tmpfs on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, tmpfs

I've got a tmpfs mounted to /var/something/else and I'd like to copy files to the location immediately after it's mounted. So if I run (or action executed after server reboot):

```
mount /var/something/else
```

1. mounted
2. files synced from hdd to tmpfs
3. a daemon started

and it would be great if I run

```
umount /var/something/else
```

1. daemon stopped
2. files synced from tmpfs to hdd
3. unmounted

Yes, it's possible to modify init/systemd script of the daemon to do all the required (mount/umount/sync). But is there another option?

The rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ does not seem to work here...if I get it right.

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: Use a standard systemd unit (service), if you have systemd. There are plenty of  examples online. No can do with udev, it works much before a mount occurs.

Comment: While searching in internet I've came across an idea that you can write custom rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` for USB drive, so that a system will detect attached drive and start a custom script if it's written so in such a rule. That's why I mentioned `udev` here.

Comment: You're probably best writing a shell script to do the mount+sync+daemon start, and a separate script to handle the unmount, then writing an initscript/systemd unit file to call the scripts at boot and shutdown. You'd control the mount via that initscript.